# Redirect to external URI from ASP.NET MVC controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, redirect

I'm trying to redirect to external url from an action method but can't get it to work. Can anybody shed some light on my error?

```
public void ID(string id)
    {
        string url = string.Empty;
        switch (id)
        {
            case "DB2FCB11-579F-4DA2-A68C-A6495B9BAAB5":

                url = "http://www.somesite.com";
                break;
        }
        Response.Redirect(url, true);
    }
```

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: What's your error? Or symptom? Does this go anywhere?

Answer (score 376, accepted):

If you're talking about ASP.NET MVC then you should have a controller method that returns the following:

```
return Redirect("http://www.google.com");
```

Otherwise we need more info on the error you're getting in the redirect. I'd step through to make sure the url isn't empty.

Comment: Optionally, you can do this instead: return new RedirectResult("yourURL", true); which is almost exactly the same, but gives you the parameter at the end to indicate whether it's a permanent redirect or not (HTTP 301 vs. something else, 307 maybe?)

Comment: @Mr.Pichler Most likely 302, but you could always check with Fiddler.

Comment: Redirect(rul) is 302 and RedirectPermanent(url) is 301.
Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17517318/redirect-vs-redirectpermanent-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Any thoughts on making this work with a local HTML file? 
Doesn't work:
> return Redirect("C:/Users/Me/Documents/test.html");

Comment: @SteveEggering check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10830212/how-to-serve-html-file-from-another-directory-as-actionresult

Comment: What about a hosted API on Azure?

Answer (score 16):

**Using JavaScript**

```
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
    return Content("<script>window.location = 'http://www.example.com';</script>");
 }
```

**Note:** As @Jeremy Ray Brown said , This is not the best option but you might find useful in some situations.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Something like this can work, but a controller decides what action to perform.  You don't need a script to be involved.

Comment: Believe it or not, something like this approach did help me. We have a hybrid ASP.NET MVC / AngularJS application with a lot of older web forms code all over the place. I used something similar to redirect to a URL that uses Angular routing. Because Angular routing follows a # mark in the URL, it is only recognized client-side, so Redirect cannot be utilized for such URLs.

Comment: @TNT Yes you are correct , I just provided this as an option, which might be useful for others.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't polite @stom. I use this approach when I need to run some script with the redirect, like count one visit at Google Analytics.

Comment: This finally works. @Yuriy 's straightforward redirect solution failed for me. For security reasons requests heading to our MVC application must crawl through proxy server - IIS with Rewrite addin + rewrite rule. This combination probably messes with redirect URL. So ie. when I want to redirect from https://example.com/action to https://www.example.org/?search=xyz, using `return Redirect("https://www.example.org/?search=xyz");` the result is redirecting to https://example.com/?search=xyz.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the solution someone is looking for is this:

```
Response.Redirect("/Sucesso")
```

This work when used in the View as well.