# Why does Response.Redirect not redirect external URL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect

Context: User is currently in the following page: http://myinternaldomain.com/page/

Issue:
When user clicks on a button in the above page, the MVC Controller method that handles this click should do some processing and redirect the user to an external domain say google.com. I tried the 2 statements below separately but both calls append the external url to the current internal page that the user is on:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("www.google.com"); // plain old HttpResponse object


return Controller.Response.Redirect("www.google.com"); // MVC Controller's response object
```

Both of the above statements result in user getting redirected to: 
    http://myinternaldomain.com/page/www.google.com
instead of just redirecting the user to www.google.com.

What am I missing here?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549324/net-mvc-redirect-to-external-url

Comment: @Ulf - this is what I currently have in the 2nd statement above - does not redirect page correctly. I have edited code to reflect this.

Comment: Nope, you're missing the http://

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to prefix your URL with "http://", like this:

```
Controller.Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: +1 (Or any schema; without the schema it is treated as a relative URL.)