# Redirecting user to external site

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, url

I want to redirect a user to an external site, outside of my ASP.NET MVC application, through a simple anchor tag. The tricky part is, the user can enter the link himself.

`<a href="@model.Url">up up and away!</a>`

If the user enters: `www.google.com` in a field (bad user), he is being redirected to `http://www.example.com/page/www.google.com`.
which is totally understandable, he should use `http://` in front of his link...

It works as expected if I hardcode the `http://`in front of the link like so: `<a href="http://@model.Url">up up and away!</a>`

BUT if the user was to enter `http://www.google.com` (good user), the browser redirects to `http://http//www.google.com` which goes nowhere..

**So now the question:** Is there a helper or method or something that routes to an external site no matter if the link contains `http://`or not? Something like `@Url.ExternalLink(model.Url)` would be great.
I could write this myself, but no need to reinvent the wheel, right? So if the wheel exists, please provide the wheel! Thanks in advance!

Checked a bunch of links, but they didn't satisfy my needs of the variable user input (never trust a user!):
[How to properly encode links to external URL in MVC Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23094174/how-to-properly-encode-links-to-external-url-in-mvc-razor) , 
[Redirect to external url from OnActionExecuting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32220691/redirect-to-external-url-from-onactionexecuting) , 
[Why does Response.Redirect not redirect external URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156760/why-does-response-redirect-not-redirect-external-url) , 
[url.Action open link in new window on ASP.NET MVC Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381949/url-action-open-link-in-new-window-on-asp-net-mvc-page) , ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use case is quite specific, MVC framework doesn't have any extension methods for this.
You need to develop it by yourself. You have the following options:

1. Create extension method (as you mentioned) for `UrlHelper` class - `@Url.ExternalLink(model.Url)`
2. Create extension method for `HtmlHelper` - `@Html.ExternalLinkFor(model => model.Url)`
3. As url comes from your model you can validate/modify it before passing to View. In this case `<a href="@model.Url">up up and away!</a>` will still be valid.
4. Add regex validator to a View where user types in url

Comment: Thanks, that's what I wanted to know, I'll develop it myself then!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily extend [UrlHelper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper(v=vs.118).aspx) with a method:

```
public static string ExternalLink(this UrlHelper helper, string uri)
{
    if (uri.StartsWith("http://")) return uri;
    return string.Format("http://{0}", uri);
}
```

Examples

```
@Url.ExternalLink("http://google.com")
@Url.ExternalLink("google.com")
```