# how to redirect to external url from c# controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services

I'm using a c# controller as web-service.

In it I want to redirect the user to an external url.

How do I do it?

Tried:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: I don't think you can do that - it's a cross-domain security violation.

Comment: How are consumers consuming the web service?

Comment: Define "as web-service."  How is the controller action being accessed?  You can send a redirect response, but if that response isn't going to a standard web browser request then it'll probably be ignored.

Comment: @David  I'm calling it from ajax POST.

Comment: @EladBenda: In that case your JavaScript code will need to handle the redirect response.  The browser won't do it automatically.  Of course, the first Google result for this was a Stack Overflow question :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to manage a redirect request after a jQuery Ajax call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call)

Comment: I understood that from your previouse answer. A strange thing. I tried  window.location.href (or without href) = 'https://www.yourdomain.com' and got 324 error. but when i typed https://www.yourdomain.com in the browser itself- I got the pgae OK

Comment: I understood that from your previouse answer. A strange thing. I tried  window.location = 'https://www.yourdomain.com' and got 324 error. but when i typed https://www.yourdomain.com in the browser itself- I got the pgae OK

Comment: @EladBenda: I'm not sure what a 324 error actually means.  I suspect that a JavaScript redirect should also contain the `http://` segment of the URL, though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [.net mvc redirect to external url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549324/net-mvc-redirect-to-external-url)

Answer (score 173, accepted):

Use the Controller's [Redirect()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirect.aspx) method.

```
public ActionResult YourAction()
{
    // ...
    return Redirect("http://www.example.com");
}
```

**Update**

You can't directly perform a server side redirect from an ajax response. You could, however, return a JsonResult with the new url and perform the redirect with javascript.

```
public ActionResult YourAction()
{
    // ...
    return Json(new {url = "http://www.example.com"});
}

$.post("@Url.Action("YourAction")", function(data) {
    window.location = data.url;
});
```

Comment: I was happy too soon. still doesn't work.  I'm calling it from ajax POST.

Comment: Are you trying to redirect the entire page or just the ajax response?

Comment: is there really a way to create anonymus type like you did? (new {url: "http://www.example.com"})

Comment: Wrong syntax, sorry. It should be `new {url = "example.com"}`.

Comment: Where do I should place the javascript part?

Comment: @dipievil the javascript should be placed in your view.

Answer (score 22):

If you are using MVC then it would be more appropriate to use [RedirectResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.redirectresult(v=vs.108).aspx) instead of using Response.Redirect.

```
public ActionResult Index() {
        return new RedirectResult("http://www.website.com");
    }
```

Reference - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rickandy/2012/03/01/response-redirect-and-asp-net-mvc-do-not-mix/

Answer (score 16):

Try this:

```
return Redirect("http://www.website.com");
```

Comment: note, you cannot use "www.website.com" - you must provide the http:// or https:// syntax

Comment: Thank you @markthewizard1234 among all the answers ive browsed, your note was the one thing that set it straight for me. I did not give it a thought as i was using a dynamic redirect to intranet sites.