# How can I redirect to a Webforms.aspx from a controller MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I have seen many forums and none work for me.

The way most simple and functional.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9739170/how-to-redirect-to-external-url-from-c-sharp-controller

Answer (score 0):

You can use Redirect for it . Call any Action where you want to redirect the page.

```
public ActionResult AnyAction()
{
   //Your code
    return Redirect("/UserWebForm.aspx");
}
```

Comment: The webform.aspx page its in the project.

Comment: @GuaGua0308 Yes but, when you run that webform.aspx page there must be some URL getting generated like hostname/somefolder/webform.aspx. I am suggesting to put that URL here in Redirect("here") if host name is same then you can user ~ for host name.