# Redirect to ActionResult from another website

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have MVC project that use with web service to get a url and then do a redirect to the URL that i get.

In the first request(the request that return me the URL in the response) i need provider some details and one of them is successUrl.

successUrl is URL that if the action of the client in the URL that i was redirect before success so redirect to successUrl.

My question is: it possible to redirect to ActionResult? if yes What i need to send in successUrl?
**Update**
For Example:

I have my MVC Project and Web Service.
My controller-

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Home()
    {
        return View("~/Views/Home/home.cshtml");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult CheckObject(someObject obj)
    {
           if (ModelState.IsValid)
           {
                ResponseWS responseWs = wsRequest(deatils);
           }
    } 

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult doSomething()
    {
       //....do something...
    }
}
```

The steps-

1. First the client go to home page from `ActionResult Home()`.
2. The client fill form and click submit and go to

   ```
   ActionResult CheckObject(someObject obj)
   ```
3. From `ActionResult CheckObject(someObject obj)` send request to WS
   with parameters that one of them urlSuccees.
4. Ws return response with URL(for the example www.test.com) that i
   need to redirect to it.
5. I do the redirect to www.test.com.
6. The client do something and if the client action was success the
   www.test.com need to redirect to my urlSuccees.

NOTE: I want that urlSuccees will be  `ActionResult doSomething()`

Thanks,

Tal

Comment: What do you mean "redirect to ActionResult"? Is your question "How do I redirect to a URL"?

Comment: Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9739170/how-to-redirect-to-external-url-from-c-sharp-controller) ?

Comment: with this you can redirect to another url . 
`return Redirect("http://www.google.com");`

Comment: @john I want redirect to controller. the web service that i use need a url for success action and i want that it do a redirect to my controller (controller function).

Comment: So what have you tried so far and what went wrong with that attempt?

Comment: For redirect i do what @alizarei suggest and i don't know what to send in the successURL for return to my controller

Comment: @tal Usually the URL for MVC controllers is something like `http://www.example.com/ControllerName/MethodName`. What you seem to be asking for is the URL of your API method?

Comment: I need do something after the action in the URL that i do the redirect.

Comment: @tal I don't understand what you're saying. API1 redirects to API2. You want to perform an action where?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160686/discussion-between-tal-and-john).

Comment: I updated my question. @john