# Visual Studio asp.net mvc project starter page shows complete url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, visual-studio, single-page-application

I have started a new angularjs SPA with Microsoft ASP.net WEBAPI. My SPA app folder resides on the server parallel to APIs folder. Hence my index file is in app folder. I right clicked on the index.html file and set it as Starter Page. The problem is when I run the app it shows all complete URL. like this

```
http://localhost:1540/Public/app/index.html
```

How do I hide it and only show

```
http://localhost:1540/
```

while running my index page as a starter page. It will be a problem when I deploy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options. [URL Rewriting](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/iis-url-rewriting-and-aspnet-routing), [manipulating the MVC Routing system](http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/asp-net-mvc-routing-intercepting-file-requests-like-index-html-and-what-it-teaches-about-how-routing-works) to serve your file or as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10830903/1453651) return the file through MVC i.e. your `HomeController`'s `Index` Action.