# How to load local html page in web form

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I wish to load a local html page in my web form.
The code I'm using looks like

```
Response.Redirect("C:\Player\Results\xyz.html", false);
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

I know there are similar questions asked but none helped me.
It would be very much helpful if someone can let me know where I'm going wrong

Thank you[image]

Comment: Kindly let me know if any additional data is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do it but I would like to mention the 2 which worked for me

In this approach the response will be redirected to the page you are passing.

```
Response.Redirect("~/Results/xyz.html", false);
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

In this below mentioned approach the content of the html page which you wish to render will be read and then passed on using OutputStream.

```
var encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
var htm = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("/Results/Html/") + "xyz.html", encoding);
byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(htm);
Response.OutputStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
Response.OutputStream.Flush();
```

Thanks to everyone who has contributed here!

Answer (score 2):

@m_beta you are using the physical path for redirection. This will necessiate you to change the code whenever you move your code location. Use relative path instead.

It would be something like below. You need to correct the path according to your location.

```
Response.Redirect("~/admin/paths.aspx", false);
```

Comment: This was the **Key part** of the question to use **relative path** instead of using physical path.

Comment: @m_beta Have you got it working when you changed to use relative part? Up vote or Mark as answer if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting to a http / https url that will respond with the static content is one thing, but no browser is going to load a local file. If browsers did that it would introduce a massive security risk.

Comment: Okay
Actually I have a service running which generates a html file as output file.
So any hint on how can I load the html file in web form 
Because if I do so then everyone can view the output file using URL.

Comment: So you are running an external process to produce the html? Then you want https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10830212/how-to-serve-html-file-from-another-directory-as-actionresult

Comment: The above given link works for me and thanks for the same but the 2nd part of your answer _but no browser is going to load a local file_ is quite misleading I would like to say.

Comment: I wouldn't call it misleading. Attempting to redirect to a file:// url would be a security concern. Having the web server, running on the local machine, return the contents of a local file, is completely different.

Answer (score 0):

You can add redirection like this also

If localhost, check your localhost value add like below

```
Response.Redirect("http://localhost:51043/xyz.html");
```

Live site

```
Response.Redirect("http://xyzdotcom/xyz.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way might be :

```
  var htmlContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Player\Results\xyz.html");
  Response.Write(htmlContent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use IFrame and use it;s SRC property to call your html page