# ASP.NET MVC - redirect to external page?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this:

```
public RedirectResult LinkRedirect(string url)
{
    return Redirect(url);
}
```

And all it does, is redirecting me to http://mysite.com/www.externalsite.com. What am I missing here?

Comment: possible dub. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549324/net-mvc-redirect-to-external-url

Comment: How is your link helping me? I have exactly the same code that was posted there, and it does not work for me!

Comment: Are you passing a url with http://prefixed to it ?

Comment: is url formatted like http://myexternalsite.com ?

Comment: No. Passed url is clear, like "www.sth.com" or "http://sth.com" etc.

Comment: I mean, i can even do `return Redirect("www.google.com");` and all it does is redirects me to `http://mysite.com/www.google.com`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass a url with `http://`prefixed to it. Then it will work

Ex: `http://www.google.com`

So if you want to allow your action method to accept all kind of links( with and without `http` prefix), you need to write little bit of code to check whether the passed the url parameter value has `http` prefix and if not, append it.

Comment: Oh well, that sucks, but okay, will do it, thanks for helping. :)