# The page is redirecting to itself after clicking on a link

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this html link:

```
<a href="~/building/delete/@item.BuildingId" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')"><i class="icon ion-android-delete"></i></a>
```

and I am using default routing in my application.

And I have this Action:

```
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
    string url = "~/";
    if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer != null)
        url = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
    try
    {
        UserRepository userRepo = new UserRepository();
        var user = userRepo.GetUser(id, 0);
        if (user != null)
        {
            return RedirectPermanent(url);
        }
        MachineRepository machineRepo = new MachineRepository();
        var machine = machineRepo.GetMachine(id, "");
        if (machine != null)
        {
            return RedirectPermanent(url);
        }
        buildingRepo.Delete(id);
    }
    catch
    {
    }
    return RedirectPermanent(url);
}
```

But when I click on my link the page is not redirect to `Delete ActionResult` and it refresh the page again. What could be wrong here?

Comment: What is the name of the class? Is it `BuildingController`?

Comment: try using @Url.Action() instead of "~/building/delete/@item.BuildingId"

Comment: @Milad It didn't worked.

Comment: have you changed your default route configuration? Try adding an `RouteAttribute` to force the routing engine to see your action. Also add an `HttpGetAttribute` and see how it goes.

Comment: @cleftheris I haven't changed default routing and HttpGet didn't solve the problem .

Comment: Try changing RedirectPermanent to Redirect. [Look this.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17517318/redirect-vs-redirectpermanent-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Change the PermamentRedirects as @HamidReza suggests and also clean the browsers cache. Your problem is that your browser remembers  the redirect and does not even bother to hit your delete controller again.