# Redirect to external url - link works in browser but not redirect method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

With reference to [.net mvc redirect to external url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549324/net-mvc-redirect-to-external-url).

So you have your controller setup with the redirect as below:

```
public ActionResult SiteDetails(short id)
{
   return Redirect("localhost:1234/Controller/Action");
}
```

BUT 

 - nothing happens when you call the action.

 - Expecting a redirect and nothing happens. 

 - Expecting a redirect to another MVC site and nothing happens. 

 - Not only that - in debug the string url going into the redirect works when copied into the browser.

Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 2):

Requires 'http://' within the string.

```
public ActionResult SiteDetails(short id)
{
   return Redirect("http://localhost:1234/Controller/Action");
}
```