# Redirect to action and open new page

Tags: c#, asp.net

in my view I have simple table with link to product:

```
<td>@Html.ActionLink("View details", "Open","Home",new { id = product.Id, url = product.Url })</td>
```

In my controller, I am doing some stuff with received data:

```
public ActionResult Open(int id, string url)
{
    productService.AddUserVisit(id);
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

And after all I am refreshing page. What I want to do is to open passed `url` in next page. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on your flow, because based on what I see you pass to an action to simply execute the same `Get` within your controller.  Not a separate controller and action.

Answer (score 1):

Can you just use

```
return Redirect(url)
```

Or if you need to go to the Index page first for some reason, you could try

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", new { url = url });
```

and obviously accept the url as a string on your index controller.

Hope that helps

Mark

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want something similar to this question here: [Redirect to external URI from ASP.NET MVC controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549324/redirect-to-external-uri-from-asp-net-mvc-controller)

Except you want to do this:

```
return Redirect(url);
```

Comment: I want to refresh current page, and open another page in another tab. What's more I cant use it in my code. I am getting `Server Error in '/' Application.`

Comment: Sounds like this should happen in javascript on the page. 

You can use window.open() documentation here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

and the function to reload page: location.reload();